# What is ruby partial class?

Tags: ruby

I read that the code snippet below implements what is called *partial class*:

```
class A
  def a
    puts 'a'
  end
end

class B < A
  def ba1
    puts 'ba1'
  end
end

class A
  def b
    puts 'b'
  end
end

class B < A
  def ba2
    puts 'ba2'
  end
end

ob = B.new
ob.a
ob.b
ob.ba1
ob.ba2
```

There are two classes `B` extended from two classes `A`. I don't understand how ruby could know which `A` the `B` is extend from. When creating an instance of `B`, how does ruby know which `B` it is? The execution result is:

```
a
b
ba1
ba2
```

The initialized `B` is an instance of two `B` classes. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Thanks @Jörg W Mittag to correct me about the definition of "partial class". I went through all answers, and I think all you guys are right. But Uri Agassi got this more clear and simple, I'd like to pick it as resolution for others reference. Thanks all again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write a class in Ruby which is *already declared*, you do not *override* the class, but rather *patch* it.

This means that ruby does not forget the older definition, but rather add upon it.

There is only one `B` class - it is the compound code in both `class B` blocks.

For example:

```
class A
  def a
    puts 'a'
  end
end

a = A.new
a.public_methods(false)
# => [:a]

class A
  def b
    puts 'b'
  end
end

a.public_methods(false)
# => [:a, :b]
```

In this example, the class `A` is changed *after* the instance of `a` is created, but, as you can see, it knows that a new method was added (`public_methods` lists the available methods for the instance).

There are things you cannot do though, for example - change the parent class of a class. If we try to take the above code, and declare another block:

```
class A < String
  def c
    puts 'c'
  end
end
# TypeError: superclass mismatch for class A
```

You get an error saying you are trying to change the base class, which is impossible (if in the initial declaration there is no inheritance declaration, the class implicitly inherits from `Object`)

Answer (score 5):

There is the only `B` class, inherited from `A`. The trick is that you are free to declare `B` in different places (which, apparently, permits you to *monkeypatch* existing classes.)

Once you have `class B < A` written, the existing `B` is being opened for extending, or a new one is being created, if there is no `B` class yet defined.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as "partial classes" in Ruby. Partial classes are a feature of C#, not Ruby.

In Ruby, a class definition expression will execute whatever is inside of it in the context of the class. You can have as many class declaration expressions as you want, it doesn't matter. This does allow you to define your class piecewise, even in different files, even in different libraries. It also allows someone *else* to (re-)define your class later on.

In Python, this is called "monkey patching" and is often frowned upon, the Ruby community has adopted this term but with a neutral meaning, because, well, in Ruby actually *all* class definition is monkey patching!

So, what you have above will

1. Amend the class definition of `A` if `A` already exists or create a new class if it doesn't.
2. Amend the class definition of `B` if `B` already exists or create a new class if it doesn't. (Should `B` already exist but have a different superclass that is not `A`, this would raise a `TypeError "superclass mismatch"`.)
3. Amend the class definition of `A` (since `A` is already defined).
4. Amend the class definition of `B` (since `B` is already defined). We could have left out the superclass, in which case the existing superclass of `B` (i.e. `A`) would have been assumed.

By the way: technically speaking, `A` and `B` are not classes. They are variables (more precisely, constants) that *refer* to classes. Classes are objects just like any other, they can be referenced by variables, passed as arguments to methods, returned from methods etc.

Also, the superclass declaration doesn't have to be a constant, it can be any arbitrary Ruby expression:

```
class Foo < if rand < 0.5 then String else Array end
end
```

is perfectly valid (and completely useless ;-) )

```
class Foo < Bar; end

def qux(sym); const_get(sym) end

class Foo < qux(:Bar); end
```

is also perfectly valid and will not generate a superclass mismatch, because the constant `Bar` and the method call `qux(:Bar)` both return the same object (which is a class).

Answer (score 2):

```
# In Ruby writing

class A
  def a; puts 'a' end
end

class A
  def b; puts 'b' end
end

# is same as writing

class A
  def a; puts 'a' end
  def b; puts 'b' end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby class definitions can be redefined. The second `class A` simply added new methods to the existing class. The second `class B < A` similarly extended the definition of `B`.